# Translate Excel formula into structured english

Tags: excel, pseudocode

I have this formula, with the variables, `m`,`s` and `e`.

```
IFERROR(IF(m - IF(s*(1/ABS(e))>m;m;s*(1/ABS(e)))>m;m;m-IF(s*(1/ABS(e))>m;m;s*(1/ABS(e))))/100;0)
```

I want to translate it to structured english, this is what I have, but I doubt its correct:

```
IF e != 0

  IF m > m
     return m

  ELSE IF s / |e| > m
    return m

  ELSE IF s / e > m
    return m - s / e

  ELSE 
    return s / e

ELSE 
  return 0

?? forgot this one upss.. s / e / 100;
```

Comment: Is that `$` sign correct? It gives me an error. Who made this monster? :P

Comment: Sorry my fault. The Dollar Sign is not supposed to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing the function, I think this simplified version has the same result:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MIN(m;s/ABS(e))<0;m;m-MIN(m;s/ABS(e)))/100;0)
```

And its logic can be explained like this:

```
if e = 0
    0
else if m - (min between s/|e| and m) > m
    m
else
    m - (min between s/|e| and m)
```

Even still, I don't understand what that is for. :P

Edit: I added a simplified Javascript version of Sir Ben's code:

```
function whacko (m,s,e) {
    if (e === 0)
        return 0;

    var value = m - Math.min(s / Math.abs(e), m);

    if (value > m)
        return m;

    return value;
};
```

Comment: Formula is for the Ad industry. Could you have a look at my take?

Comment: I have already spent all my energies understanding the Excel formula. :P Why don't you try my formula to see if it behaves like yours with your data so you can use this simpler algorithm in Javascript?

Comment: Wow man... Updating my answer with your codebase. The simplification also is awesome. I really tried. How come you solved it?

Comment: I analyzed what each part of the function did, first replaced repeated things like `s/|e|` and then `min between s/|e| and m` with variables to make it simpler, and then just tried to understand the logic by separating the if-else blocks. Finally I played with `Excel` with the possible combination of data to verify my logic. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andrew's great reply, this is the working code in JS:

```
var m = 33
  , s = 43
  , e = 12.75; // Excel: 29,6%

function whacko (m,s,e) {

    if (e === 0) {

        return 0;

    } else if (m - (Math.min(s/Math.abs(e), m)) > m) {

        return m;

    } else {

        return m - (Math.min(s/Math.abs(e), m));

    }
};

console.log(whacko(m,s,e)); // 29.627450980392158
```

Comment: You should definitely store `m - Math.min(s/Math.abs(e), m)` in a variable. :) Also remember that as `return`s exit from the function, there's no need to have an `else` after it. This way you can create this variable afterwards without worrying about scope.

Comment: Just added it to my answer. :)